# SimpleAudioPlayer + sleep function

Tags: arduino-due, audio, sleep, sound

I have tested the SimpleAudioPlayer example.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayer

This works fine, but when I add a `sleep(1000)` at the end of the `loop()` function, the music sounds dismembered (second run).

```
void loop()
{
    // ... source from the example 

    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("End of file. Thank you for listening!");

    sleep(1000);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

`sleep()` is something different. You are probably want to use `delay(1000)` instead.

`sleep()` comes from libsam and is not very well documented for use within the Arduino environment. There is probably a conflicting timer or interrupt between `sleep()` and the `Audio.h` library. So sticking with `delay()` is probably your best option.